# Navigating Directories and Counting files in a directory with Python

Tags: python, parsing, directory

I am fairly familiar with Python and coding in general but I do not have much experience with the parsing and directory navigation in Python. I have a file that contains some data that I wish to extract and I want to be able to count the number of files and directories in given directory. I have done a little research and I think the sys and os.path modules will be useful. Also do the commands for os.path vary across platforms(Yosemite vs. Linux. Windows)

Comment: You got it right. `os` module will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`len(os.listdir('path'))` will give you the total number of entries at `'path'` (this includes files and directories). As far as I know, the `os` module is platform independent, however the strings used for paths are different for windows and unix-based environments (and maybe others, I don't know). Windows path strings should look like `'C:\\directory\\subdir\\file'` because backslashes need to be escaped. I can't remember off the top of my head but I think linux path strings are just like you'd expect them to be: `'directory/subdir/file'`.

Comment: So os.listdir('path') returns an array filled with the files and directories in 'path'?